# Java - Create an return a Stub interface inside a method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this interface

```
public interface MQTTClient {

     public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message);

}
```

for Testing purposes I would like to make a configuration class like this

```
@Configuration
public class TestServiceConfig {


    @Bean
    public MQTTClient mqttClient() {

        return new {

        public class MQTTClientImpl implements MQTTClient {


            @Override
            public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this is posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible, there are generally 3 ways to do this:

1. like you did, implement it by yourself, you may need `@Primary` to make sure spring loads this one.
2. You don't need to implement it by yourself, consider use mocking framework like `Mockito`, you will just need to do it like this:

   ```
   @Primary
   @Bean
   public MQTTClient mqttClient() {
       return Mockito.mock(MQTTClient.class);
   }
   ```
3. If you are using `spring-boot`, you can use the annotation `@MockBean` since version `1.4.x`

Answer (score 1):

you have to use unit tests for test purpose not in configuration file.
you have to declare inner class or create anonymous class.In this example you are trying to create object and class declaration in the same block.So java can't create object of not declared class.First declare class then create object of this class.

Anonymous:

```
   return new MQTTClient {
           @Override
           public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           }
   }
```

Inner class:

```
   class MQTTClientImpl implements MQTTClient {

       @Override
       public void prepareAndSend(String recipient, String message) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
    }

    public MQTTClient mqttClient() {
       return new MQTTClientImpl();
    }
```

Note:

> actually if you are testing interface it means you are waiting for
>   implemenation of this interface.So inner class or anonymous class is
>   not proper for this purpose.Because test level must be seperated from
>   bussiness level.Otherwise later you will get confused in your code.If
>   you just suppose that implementation passed and continue the rest of
>   the app then use mocking.When the real implementation comes use the
>   real implementation class to test.